# What event is fired when the cancel button is clicked?

Tags: winforms

Is there a way I can cancel editing on my form without adding a cancel button?

I am looking for a way to call `CancelButton.PerformClick()`  when I don't have a cancel button.

In the form code I have added the following - but need to know how to cancel the editing.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if(keyData == Keys.Escape) {
    // What goes here?
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

The form contains text controls , and a BindingNavigator

It turns out that I can accomplish what I need using

```
navigator.BindingSource.CancelEdit();
```

however I wondered it there way of calling something like 
   `form.CancelButton.PerformClick()` if the `form.CancelButton` is not set.

Comment: Can you provide more detail. Like, what are you editing that you want cancelled? Do you have some Cancellation function? Hard to decipher this question.

Comment: i edited it, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can cancel editing on my form without adding a cancel button?
>
> I am looking for a way to call CancelButton.PerformClick() when I don't have a cancel button.

In a word, no. There is no cancel button unless you've created one. The `Form.CancelButton` property will not specify any object unless you've assigned an object to it.

However, there may be a way to achieve what you seek to accomplish. Think about this: what would happen if you *did* have a cancel button? What would that cancel button do?

It would close the form, discarding all of the user's changes, right? So why not just close the form? Something like:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if(keyData == Keys.Escape) {
    this.Close();
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

If you need to do more clean-up on cancellation (e.g., whatever you would normally put in the cancel button's `Click` event handler method), you could just define a form class-level method called something like `CancelForm`, and then call that. For example:

```
private void CancelForm() {
  // do cleanup
  this.Close(); 
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if(keyData == Keys.Escape) {
    this.CancelForm();
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Then again, I question your motivation for wanting to do this. If you want to support cancellation, why not just add a cancel button? Why does the user need to memorize keyboard commands? Keyboard commands are *great* for users who *want* to use them, but there's a reason that GUIs are so popular. If the user should be able to cancel the operation, give 'em a big ol' cancel button for them to click. Be sure to disable it when cancelling is not available, giving instant visual feedback.

As a bonus, when you set the `Form.CancelButton` property to a cancel button on your form, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key automatically invokes the cancel button, freeing you from overriding `ProcessCmdKey`. You seem to be trying to solve the problem backwards. WinForms takes care of all this for you automagically when you follow the standard idioms. And there are some really good reasons for following the standard idioms.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. I have been trying to write a "handle it all" toolbar for all data entry forms to inherit. Hence My reason for not following the idiom... but maybe I should put a cancel button on the toolbar.

Comment: @kirsteng That's what I'd do, yes. Solves two problems at once. I've found that programmers like you and I are strange. We *like* learning and using keyboard shortcuts. People like my mother are always there to remind me that is unusual among computer users. :-)